# Backbone.js model trigger change only if model.on called again

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone-model

It's my first post here so please be nice ;) I'm trying to create a Backbone+requireJS sample app and I have stumbled upon a strange problem. In my views initialize function I bind to models change event by

```
this.model.on("change", this.change());
```

Event is triggered correctly when data is loaded and all is fine. In my view I also bind to a click event. On click I try to change one of the properties and I was hoping for a change event, but it never came.

I was trying some stuff recommended here on stackoverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909799/backbone-js-change-not-firing-on-model-changene-js-change-not-firing-on-model-change), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513020/backbone-js-change-event-not-firing), [and there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959737/trigger-backbone-js-change-when-value-doesnt-change)) but with no luck.

In my guts I feel it has to do with event binding. When I tried to bind again to models on change event inside click callback it started to work. So now I sit here and I'm, hm, confused. Could someone shed some light on this issue?

My View:

```
define(
[
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/news/newsListItem.html'
 ],
 function($, _, Backbone, newsListItemTemplate)
 {
    var NewsListItemViewModel = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        events: {
            "click a" : "onLinkClick"
        },
        initialize: function(){
            this.model.on("change", this.changed());
        },
        render: function()
        {
            this.$el.html(_.template(newsListItemTemplate, this.model.toJSON()));
        },
        changed: function()
        {
            this.render();
            console.log("changed");
        },
        //GUI functions
        onLinkClick: function(e)
        {
            console.log("click!");
            this.model.toggle();
            this.model.on("change", this.changed());

        }

    });

    var init = function(config){
        return new NewsListItemViewModel(config);
    }

    return {
        init : init
    }
 }
```

);

My Model:

```
define(
['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
function($, _, Backbone){

    var NewsListItemModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        toggle: function() {
            this.set('done', !this.get('done'));
            this.trigger('change', this);
        }
    });

    var init = function(data)
    {
        return new NewsListItemModel(data);
    }

    return {
        init: init,
        getClass: NewsListItemModel
    };
}
```

);

Thanks for any input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use a *function* as event handler - not its result. 
Hence, change the line into this:

```
this.model.on("change", this.changed.bind(this));
```

As it stands now, you actually fire `this.changed()` function just once - and assign its result (which is `undefined`, as the function doesn't have `return` statement) to be the model's `change` event handler.

Second, you shouldn't rebind this handler in `onLinkClick`: once bound, it'll stay here. It looks like it's more appropriate to `trigger` this event instead:

```
onLinkClick: function(e)
{
  console.log("click!");
  this.$el.toggle();
  this.model.trigger('change');
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked! Code under onLinkClick contains my debug code, rebinding was only a test to check if rebinding worked. I have also been looking now on [todos](http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html) and there they bind in init as fallows:

this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);

is it recommended way to bind to model?